# changing layout image dynamically more then once

Tags: android, xml, layout

[image: my layout is like]

in linear 1,3 i'm displaying transparent buttons
 and 1 want linear 2 to be parent layout and

set its image  to continuously change  3-4 times

I thought of using **setBackgroundResource**

but it would change only once ,**how to show images in a flow

like image 1,image2....so on** ,if i use relative layout

still same prob ,new in development so kindly guide

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I got it correctly but if you want to change Images one after the other you can try Animation Drawable
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

For Showing stuff one over the other you should generally use Frame Layout.
Can You also elaborate your question a bit

Comment: thanx ,this helped me a bit but can we add a layer using

Comment: frame.addframe(xml,duration) but is not accepting it,the xml may contain textview ,button etc

Comment: addFrame method will not accept xml I think...If you want to change from 1 view to another you should consider using a viewflipper.which can allow you to show different views and flip them using a timer task or countdown timer

Comment: thanx,yes I thought of that ,but viewflipper is used to flip chid ,I want to flip the parent (linear 2 as above image),which acts as background to linear 1 ,linear 3

Comment: I added two relative layout under parent and added and displayed images and then swapped layout to show change of background,that worked for me